# Accessing model attributes in views (application.html.erb specifically)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on an application that someone else wrote, trying to add some enhancements and UI tweaks.

I want something along the lines of the Devise 'current_user' helper which I can use in my view to alter the UI a little bit. But all the authentication and authorization is hand-written.

Ideally, I want to be able to do something along the lines of the following:

```
<% if current_user.interface_id == 1 %>
    <%= link_to 'Something', something_path %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to 'Something Else', something_else_path %>
<% end %>
```

Thoughts on the best way to go about implementing something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a `current_user` object available to both your controllers and views, you could add something like this to `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`:

```
helper_method :current_user
def current_user
  @current_user ||= ..... # Punch in the logic here that retrieves the current user from the session, etc.
end
```